# AngularJS: Error while sending a javascript array (POST) to REST (Java+Jersey)

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, json

I'm currently working in the migration of a system from Sencha ExtJS to Angular and well, I'm having problems sending an array of objects to a REST Web Service (developed in Java using Jersey).

Basically, my array looks like:

[image]

It has two objects (but it can handle more items for sure), the name of the variable holding this array is: "data". The angular code I'm using is a basic "$http.post":

```
$http.post('/sys/rest/sysadmin/news/sysappdownloads/', data);
```

And the method in the REST service looks like:

```
@POST
@Path("sysappdownloads")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void updateDownloadsEnvironments(List<SysDownloadsEnv> environmentsList) {
    log.debug("updateDownloadsEnvironments() - requested to update environments for ETMS downloads: {}", environmentsList);
    getDelegate().updateEnvironmentInfo(environmentsList);
    log.debug("updateDownloadsEnvironments() - process ended successfully");
}
```

The method is receiving a List of objects that has the same values/attributes as the objects stored in the array.

But I'm receiving the following stack trace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<com.mci.etms.cmn.exception.UnexpectedException id="1">
  <detailMessage>Unexpected Runtime error occurred (javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException)</detailMessage>
  <cause class="java.lang.Exception" id="2">
    <detailMessage>[javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException(sanitized)] null</detailMessage>
    <stackTrace id="3">
      <trace id="4">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.TerminatingRule.accept(TerminatingRule.java:66)</trace>
      <trace id="5">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)</trace>
      <trace id="6">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)</trace>
      <trace id="7">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)</trace>
      <trace id="8">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1542)</trace>
      <trace id="9">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1473)</trace>
      <trace id="10">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1419)</trace>
      <trace id="11">com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1409)</trace>
      <trace id="12">com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:409)</trace>
      <trace id="13">com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:540)</trace>
      <trace id="14">com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:715)</trace>
      <trace id="15">javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)</trace>
      <trace id="16">weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)</trace>
      <trace id="17">weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)</trace>
      <trace id="18">weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)</trace>
      <trace id="19">weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)</trace>
      <trace id="20">weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)</trace>
      <trace id="21">com.mci.etms.server.filter.InboundHTTPRequestFilter.doFilter(InboundHTTPRequestFilter.java:55)</trace>
      <trace id="22">weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)</trace>
      <trace id="23">weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3715)</trace>
      <trace id="24">weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)</trace>
      <trace id="25">weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)</trace>
      <trace id="26">weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)</trace>
      <trace id="27">weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)</trace>
      <trace id="28">weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)</trace>
      <trace id="29">weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)</trace>
      <trace id="30">weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)</trace>
      <trace id="31">weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)</trace>
    </stackTrace>
  </cause>
  <stackTrace id="32">
    <trace id="33">com.mci.etms.server.corba.ExceptionConverter.basicConvertAndThrow(ExceptionConverter.java:193)</trace>
    <trace id="34">com.mci.etms.server.corba.ExceptionConverter.convertAndThrow(ExceptionConverter.java:134)</trace>
```

I tried using JSON.parse, JSON.stringify and angular.parse. Do you know if Angular has a special way to handle the post or I need to format the data somehow?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "The method is receiving a List of objects that has the same values/attributes as the objects stored in the array." - is this the problem or the desired outcome? What does not work?

Comment: My bad, sorry I forgot to add the stacktrace. Problem is while posting the array, based on that array I make an update in the database through the REST service. Method will not return value, it's just a void type.

Comment: Your problem is still hard to understand to me. If you set a breakpoint on `log.debug("updateDownloadsEnvironments()`, does it get called? Could you please add the Angular **code** that does the POST? And what is actually in `environmentsList` on the Java side?